# Unable to capture audio input in Android TV with AudioRecord - Java

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, microphone, television

I've been developing a software that uses the "AudioRecord" class for getting microphone input and afterwards it processes it to detect X frequencies on the sound.

Example:

```
 AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT, SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, AUX);
 recorder.startRecording();
```

It works with an AsyncTask, recording as a back process. I'm also using the following permissions:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

And I'm granting them correctly on my Android TV device.

I've been testing it on the Android Studio emulator and on a few phones and it works flawless, but when I try to use the APP on my Android TV (MiBox HD) it almost doesn't capture audio, it doesn't detects anything most of the time and only works by a few seconds after trying many times.

I know that the microphone on the Android TV is usually on the pad or controller so I'm not sure if I am missing something.

What I'm doing wrong? I'am missing something?

Comment: It is possible that the MiBox microphone is only usable for certain MiBox functions, not for ordinary apps. Use `PackageManager` and `hasSystemFeature()` with `FEATURE_MICROPHONE` to see whether the MiBox advertises that it has a microphone.

Comment: That's it... Seems that they disabled it on the last Oreo update :(

Thank you very much I was getting mad with this.

Comment: @SergiBarjola : Any luck in recording audio in Android TV via controller's mic ? 
Any idea how to record audio from ATV's controller's mic?

Comment: I haven't been successful so far... Sad :(

Comment: @SergiBarjola any update? I want to try audio input as well on Android TV !!!

Comment: I got it tested on a Fire TV running Nougat and `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION` worked and actually recorded audio. DEFAULT and MIC did'nt work. And it also needs the mic button to be held.